# Python: dataframe pivot with duplicate labels

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot

I have a panda dataframe as below

```
index   ColumnName ColumnValue
0        A          1
1        B          2
2        C          3
3        A          4
4        B          5
5        C          6
6        A          7
7        B          8
8        C          9
```

I want ouput like below as panda dataframe

```
A     B       C  
1     2       3
4     5       6
7     8       9
```

Can anyone sugget how i can i achieve desired output ?

Regards
Vipul

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's a little unclear what you are asking. Can you edit the question with the data in the correct format so that people can understand and help? Also reading this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solution came into my mind is to use `for` loop with unique columnName as below. If you want `pivot` method to achieve it, someone else might help you.

```py
columns = df['ColumnName'].unique()
data = {}
for column in columns:
    data[column] = list(df[df['ColumnName'] == column]['ColumnValue'])
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

which will give you the below output

```
    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
```

Comment: Thanks Prince Francis, that fixed my problem.